# Dijkstra algorithm on scheme

Tags: algorithm, scheme, racket, dijkstra

I have created pretty much every procedure needed for my Dijkstra algorithm to work but I am having some problems with the shortestpath procedure, I wrote it on paper but can't get it to work on scheme

```
(define (shortestpath origin destiny graph)
  (define (update x)
    (begin
      (set! new-dist (+ (dist-between n x graph)
                         (dist-info-node (get-info-node i n))))
      (when (< new-dist (dist-info-node (get-info-node i v)))
        (update-previous-dist-node i v new-dist n))))
```

Above is the main procedure which is giving me an error on the 4th line

```
(define (get-info-node i n)
  (define (get-info-node-aux i n cont)
    (if (equal? n (vector-ref (no-info-no i) cont))
        (vector-ref i cont)
        (get-info-node-aux i n (+ cont 1))))
  (get-info-node-aux i n 0))


(define (dist-info-node i)
  (vector-ref i 1))

   (define new-dist 0)
```

The error I'm getting is **"expand: unbound identifier in module in: i"** on the 4th line

```
(define (update-previous-dist-node! i n d a)
  (define (update-previous-dist-node!-aux i n d a cont)
    (if (equal? n (vector-ref (no-info-no i) cont))
        (begin
          (modify-dist! (vector-ref i cont) d)
          (modify-previous! (vector-ref i cont) a))
        (update-previous-dist-node!-aux i n d a (+ cont 1))))
  (update-previous-dist-node!-aux i n d a 0))
```

All procedures are defined as they should but the main one is not working properly. This was wrote on paper first, I have tried everything and I must be missing something

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though you've structured your program as a number of small functions defined inside of a larger one.  This is a bad idea.  The advantage (inner procedures can refer to origin, destination and graph) is outweighed by the inability to test the helper functions independently. If I were debugging this function, I would:

- pull the inner functions up to the top level,
- create purpose statements for each one, and
- write a few test cases for each one.

Answer (score 0):

The only variable bound in the inner function update is x. The only variables bound in the outer function shortestpath are origin, destiny and graph. You get the error message because i is not bound. Neither are n or v. You need to either pass i, n and v into the outer functions, or define them as global variables, or bind them with a let inside the function.